# Restoring .dump file - "Permission Denied"

Tags: postgresql, centos, psql, postgresql-9.4, pg-restore

I am setting up a website and am having some trouble restoring a database .dump file. I am using centos7, selinux, postgresql 9.4, and apache2.

This is [my pg_hba.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq7Z6.png).

[image]

This is the command I am trying to move the dump:

```
psql --single-transaction -U postgres db_name < dump_location
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> Permission denied.

Am I missing something or is there someway I should alter my settings? Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you!

Comment: You should post the entire error message as it was output by psql.

Comment: What Linux user are you logged in as when running that command? Can you get a psql prompt if you just give `psql -U postgres db_name` by itself?

Comment: @Harmic I can get a psql prompt if I just give  psql -U postgres db_name by itself. I am logged in as the postgres user when I am logged on

Comment: @Mike This is what the full message looks like:
bash-4.2$ psql --single-transaction db_name < file.dump
bash: file.dump: Permission denied

Comment: Then it looks like @Craig is right on this one, you do not have permissions to that file or the current directory you are in.  This is not a psql problem but a linux filesystem permissions problem..

Answer (score 1):

The operating system user you are running your shell as does not have permission to read the path `dump_location`.

Note that this is *not* necessarily the operating system user you run `psql` as. In a statement like:

```
sudo -u postgres psql mydb < /some/path
```

then `/some/path` is read *as the current user, before `sudo`*, not as user `postgres`, because it's the *shell* that performs the input redirection, not `psql`.

If, in the above example, you wanted to read the file as user `postgres` you would:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -f /some/path mydb
```

That instructs `psql` to open and read `/some/path` when it's started.

Comment: When I check for permissions with ls -lZ file.dump, I get the following: -rw-r--r--. Doesn't this mean all other users have read permissions?

Comment: I seem to have answered my own question: the directory in which the file.dump is stored has the following permission: drwx------. I will try changing it with chmod.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you are using correct database user and you have at least read permission on the dump file.

"psql -d  -U postgres -f "

will work.